# Paired bar chart with conditional labeling based on multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr, dplyr

I am trying to create a graphical output like the picture below for the following sample of data but the code I have included gives an error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Column `n` must be length 43 (the number of rows) or one, not 42.

My goal is to plot all providers from the same location on the same chart and then only include one name on the axis so that each provider can see how they compare to others in their area without revealing the identity of the other providers. I have tried specifying that n= 43 (the length of the full dataset) but have not had any success. Additionally, I would like to do a paired bar chart to show how each provider compares the their previous months' rates. 
[image]

```
  Provider  Month   Payment Location
    Andrew  2   32.62   OH
    Dillard 2   40  OH
    Henry   2   32.28   OH
    Lewis   2   47.79   IL
    Marcus  2   73.04   IL
    Matthews    2   45.22   NY
    Paul    2   65.73   NY
    Reed    2   27.67   NY
    Andrew  1   33.23   OH
    Dillard 1   36.63   OH
    Henry   1   42.68   OH
    Lewis   1   71.45   IL
    Marcus  1   39.51   IL
    Matthews    1   59.11   NY
    Paul    1   27.67   NY
    Reed    1   28.78   NY

library(tidyverse)
    library(purrr)
    df <- 1:nrow(PaymentsFeb) %>% 
         purrr::map( ~PaymentsFeb) %>% 
         set_names(PaymentsFeb$Provider) %>% 
         bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
         nest(-ID) %>%  

     mutate(Location=map2(data,ID, ~.x %>% filter(Provider == .y) %>% select(Location))) %>% 
     mutate(data=
           map2(data, ID, ~.x %>% 
                  mutate(n=paste0("#", sample(seq_len(n()), size = n())),
                         Provider=ifelse(Provider == .y, as.character(Provider), n),
                         Provider=factor(Provider, levels = c(.y, sample(n, n())))))) %>%
     mutate(plots=map2(data,Location, ~ggplot(data=.x,aes(x = Provider, y = scores, fill = scores))+ 
               geom_col() +geom_text(aes(label=Per.Visit.Bill.Rate), vjust=-.3)+
               ggtitle("test scores by Location-  February 2018", subtitle = .y$Location)
     ))
```

Comment: I would guess a wrapper for scale_x_discrete, with variables for `breaks =`  and `labels=`, might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding one label to each bar graph r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393570/adding-one-label-to-each-bar-graph-r)

Comment: I realized that the question I flagged this as a duplicate of was also posted by you. How does this question differ from your previous one exactly?